# how to select data from multiple tables using dropdown using a search term?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to fetch the data from multiple tables using a search term. Actually there is a database containing genes information for different themes like diet, inflammation etc. There are some genes which are common in few themes like SIRT1 is common in both diet as well as inflammation but when i am trying to fetch the information of this gene by multiple selection of themes i.e. tables but it is showing only for one theme i.e. only from one table.  below is the code for multiple selection of tables in html which is working to select multiple options but not able to select multiple tables from the database.

```
<form method="post" action="test3.php" name="search_form">
    <p align="center">
    <input type="text" name="search" size=15 maxlength=15 >
    <select name="table" size = "2" multiple>
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="infla_info">Inflammation</option>
    <option value="diet_info">diet</option>
    <option value="obesity_info">obesity</option>
    <option value="stress_info">stress</option>
    <option value="atherosclerosis_info">atherosclerosis</option>
    <option value="retinopathy_info">Diabetic Retinopathy</option>
    <option value="nephropathy_info">Diabetic Nephropathy</option>
    <option value="neuropathy_info">Diabetic Neuropathy</option>
    </select>
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Gene Search">
    </p>
    </form>
```

after this php code to fetch the information for given gene in selected tables is given below:

```
  <?php
    $table=$_POST['table'];
    $search=$_POST['search'];

    if ($search == "" or $table=="")
    {
    echo"<a href='a.html'> back </a>";
    echo "<p>You forgot to enter the Gene Name";
    exit;
    }
    else
    {

   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "t2diacod");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 //$table = array("diet_info","infla_info","blue","yellow"); 
 // if (is_array($table))
 // {
 //foreach ($table as $t){  

    if ($table=="diet_info")
    {

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from diet_info where Gene_symbol = '$search'");
    $num_row=$sql->num_rows;

    if ($num_row == 0)
    {
    echo "Sorry, Invalid Gene Name.";
    }
   else
   {
  echo "<h1> DIET </h1>";

    echo "<table border='0', width='1000'>
<tr>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Locus_Id</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Gene_Symbol</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Gene_Name</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Synonyms</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Chromosome</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Gene Summary</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Homologene_Id</font></th>
</tr>";
    for($i=0;$i<$num_row;$i++)
{

$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
  echo "<tr bgcolor = '#E6E6FA'>";
    $strName2 = $result["Locus_id"];
  $strLink2 = "<a href = 'diet_gene_go.php?gene_id=" . $result['Locus_id'] . "'>" . $strName2 . "</a>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $strLink2 . "</td>";
  $strName1 = $result["Gene_symbol"];
  $strLink1 = "<a href = 'diet_gene_symbol.php?gene_symbol=" . $result['Gene_symbol'] . "'>" . $strName1 . "</a>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $strLink1 . "</td>";
  echo "<td align=center>" . $result['Gene_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align=center>" . $result['Synonymns'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align=center>" . $result['Chromosome_no'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td height='50px'><div style='height:200px; width:400px; overflow:scroll;'>" . $result['Gene_summary'] . "</div></td>";
 //$strName = $result['FirstName'] . " " . $result['LastName']
      $strName = $result["Homologene_id"];

       // Create a link to person.php with the id-value in the URL
       // $strLink = "<a href = 'person.php?id = " . $result['id'] . "'>" . $strNavn . "</a>";
  $strLink = "<a href = 'diet_homologene.php?homologene_id=" . $result['Homologene_id'] . "'>" . $strName . "</a>";

   echo "<td align=center>" . $strLink . "</td>";
  // echo "<td align=center>" . $result['PMID'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

    //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that


}
   }
    }

    if ($table=="infla_info")
    {

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from infla_info where Gene_symbol = '$search'");
    $num_row=$sql->num_rows;

    if ($num_row == 0)
    {
    echo "Sorry, Invalid Gene Name or you are looking at the wrong place double check the Gene name and search it again.";
    }
   else
   {
       echo "<h1> Inflammation </h1>";
       echo "<table border='0', width='1000'>
<tr>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Locus_Id</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Gene_Symbol</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Gene_Name</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Synonyms</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Chromosome</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Gene Summary</font></th>
<th bgcolor = '#2F4F4F' align = center><font color = '#fff'>Homologene_Id</font></th>
</tr>";
        for($i=0;$i<$num_row;$i++)
{

$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
  echo "<tr bgcolor = '#E6E6FA'>";
    $strName2 = $result["Locus_id"];
  $strLink2 = "<a href = 'infla_gene_go.php?gene_id=" . $result['Locus_id'] . "'>" . $strName2 . "</a>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $strLink2 . "</td>";
  $strName1 = $result["Gene_symbol"];
  $strLink1 = "<a href = 'infla_gene_symbol.php?gene_symbol=" . $result['Gene_symbol'] . "'>" . $strName1 . "</a>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $strLink1 . "</td>";
  echo "<td align=center>" . $result['Gene_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align=center>" . $result['Synonymns'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align=center>" . $result['Chromosome_no'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td height='50px'><div style='height:200px; width:400px; overflow:scroll;'>" . $result['Gene_summary'] . "</div></td>";
 //$strName = $result['FirstName'] . " " . $result['LastName']
      $strName = $result["Homologene_id"];

       // Create a link to person.php with the id-value in the URL
       // $strLink = "<a href = 'person.php?id = " . $result['id'] . "'>" . $strNavn . "</a>";
  $strLink = "<a href = 'infla_homologene.php?homologene_id=" . $result['Homologene_id'] . "'>" . $strName . "</a>";

   echo "<td align=center>" . $strLink . "</td>";
  // echo "<td align=center>" . $result['PMID'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

    //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that


}
   }

    } ....... and so on for all tables
```

please help me to get what i want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change name of multi selection dropdown. Make its name with `[]` (to post an array to php with multiple selected values)

So, change `name="table"` to `name="table[]"`

```
<select name="table[]" size = "2" multiple>
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="infla_info">Inflammation</option>
    <option value="diet_info">diet</option>
    <option value="obesity_info">obesity</option>
    <option value="stress_info">stress</option>
    <option value="atherosclerosis_info">atherosclerosis</option>
    <option value="retinopathy_info">Diabetic Retinopathy</option>
    <option value="nephropathy_info">Diabetic Nephropathy</option>
    <option value="neuropathy_info">Diabetic Neuropathy</option>
</select>

<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Gene Search">
</p>
</form>
```

And from `PHP` you need to do loop for each selections as below:

```
$tables=$_POST['table'];

//test for table selection, (validation)
if(count($tables)==0){
    echo "Please select table to search in.";
}else{
    foreach($tables as $table){   //perform search for each selected tables
        //you might want to use switch case here
        switch($table){
            case "infla_info":
                    //code to search in infla_info table
                    break;

            case "diet_info":
                    //code to search in diet_info table

            ...
            ...
        }    
    }
}
```